# How to convert integer number to latitude and longitude

Tags: gps, hex, blob, latitude-longitude

Initially the data was in BLOB field of SQLite database then -> hex data -> decimal data.

```
(ëÑ·,Êz¾5)->(14EBD1B7, CA7ABE35)->(350998860, 3397041663)
```

Finally, I got a set like this:

```
longitude

350998860
350998914
350998914
350998914
350999021
350998967
350998967
350998967
350998914
350998967
350999021

Latitude

3397041663
3397041717
3397041663
3397041556
3397041610
3397041610
3397041556
3397041610
3397041610
3397041663
3397041610
3397041663
```

I know the data was taken close to the university of Memphis with `Latitude:N 35° 7' 6.9956"
Longitude:W 89° 56' 13.204"`. But I have not found any way to obtain a similar values from this dataset. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

taking reference from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19408447/longitude-reading-measured-in-degrees-with-a-1x10-7-degree-lsb-signed-2-s-comp) i wrote following function and it is working perfectly:

```
Private Function ConvertHexToLatLng(h As String) As Double
    Dim intDec As Integer
    intDec = Convert.ToInt32(h, 16)
    Dim dblLatOrLng As Double
    If intDec < Convert.ToInt32("7FFFFFFF", 16) Then
        dblLatOrLng = intDec * 0.0000001
    Else
        dblLatOrLng = 0 - ((Convert.ToInt32("FFFFFFFF", 16) - intDec) * 0.0000001)
    End If
    Return dblLatOrLng
End Function
```