# Java byte[] to float value conversion

Tags: java

I have a byte array with length 4

```
byte[] h = new byte[4];
h[0] = 0x13;
h[1]=(byte)0xBF;
h[2]=(byte)0x71;
h[3]=(byte)0xA8;
```

which is a latitude value (actual value is 33.1313576)
i am converting it into float with following statement:

```
ByteBuffer.wrap(h).getFloat()
```

output is 4.8327252E-27

Comment: Show us how you got from `33.1313576` to a `byte[]`.

Comment: we get it through a endpoint creation logic is not known.

Comment: So how do you know it's meant to represent that latitude?

Comment: the binary representaton in single precision float of 4.8327252E-27 is 0x13bf71a8, and 33.1313576 is 0x42048683. Check it [here](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html). How do you expect those bytes to be 33.1313576?

Comment: 13BF71A8     Latitude (33.1313576)
BA18A506     Longitude (-117.2790010)  iam getting these in  upd packets

Comment: @babravahan It's UDP, not 'upd'. I think *you* need to check some issues yourself. You also need to be a lot more specific. "Check how C language interprets 33.1313576" is meaningless in the absence of C code, and without specifying the platform, or the UDP protocol you're using. As a matter of fact 0x13BF71A8 = 331313576 without any scaling.

Comment: found a similar issue in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19408447/longitude-reading-measured-in-degrees-with-a-1x10-7-degree-lsb-signed-2-s-comp but here they are converting in javascript but what iam looking for is Java

Comment: Come off it. The logic is identical, and the syntax nearly so. You just have to convert the hex to binary and then scale. Nothing to do with ByteBuffer whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

You are mistaken. The byte representation of 33.1313576f as a `float` is 0x42048683 according to both Java and [this online calculator](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html?decimal=051051046049051049051053055054).

What you actually have is not a float at all, it is an *integer,* that needs to be scaled by 1/1000000 or whatever it is.